# How to create a table in Snowflake, but prevent dropping it under the same role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-grant

We have build a streaming pipeline that has the rights **to create new tables** in snowflake when they are created in the source system. *(running under the role PROD_EL_ROLE)*

Even though we have time travel enabled *'for backup'*, I want to prevent the PROD_EL_ROLE itself from being able to *'accidentally'* DROP tables. AFAIK, this cannot be done directly as the creator of a table in snowflake is also the owner, and thus, is also allowed to drop the table

What I tried in addition, is to transfer the owner to another role **higher** in our RBAC hierarchy (PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE) . This unfortunately **only** works by using REVOKE GRANTS, which is not what we want as with the creating of a table under PROD_EL_ROLE various privileges are auto-created by various FUTURE GRANTS. And we obviously don't want to remove them.

If I use COPY GRANTS, it does not work due to the PROD_EL_ROLE not having the MANAGE GRANTS right. Which is a grant we obviously **do not want to give** to PROD_EL_ROLE...
I only want to prevent table dropping by PROD_EL_ROLE

**Any idea how to solve this?**

Comment: Is it possible to leverage PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE to create the table initially in your workflow?  You can switch roles as part of your workflow just for table generation statements, and then use PROD_EL_ROLE for further DML?  Not ideal, but it'd work, I think.

Comment: Technically that would be possible @MikeWalton, however then we run into the same problem: PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE has the righs to create and drop any table / then we need to include the right to let our streamer operate under the PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE. Then we have the same problem. What we want, is the streamer code to ONLY be able to CREATE tables, and never DROP...

Comment: If you have a role that only creates tables inside your automated workstream, then what's the risk of that role dropping a table?  I'm just trying to get to the root of the issue, since any object that is created is owned by the creator and can be dropped by the creator, then you need to either isolate the creator, or move ownership to another role after the object is created.

Comment: Also, per your post regarding COPY GRANTS, could you use the PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE to GRANT OWNERSHIP on the table?  You could grant that role the ability to manage grants in your schema (or use a managed schema).  That might work, too.

Comment: Hi @mike, the risk is twofold: 1) someone making a coding error, accidentally dropping all tables in prod. Would not be the first time in history that happens :). 2) Take-over of the login / point of attack / security risk. So what I indeed want to do is move ownership to another role from the same role that created the table. But that is not possible in a way a want (keeping all other existing grants excluding ownership

Comment: @MikeWalton, While I could indeed use the PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE to grant that that ownership, this requires a separate login / role switch to do this or a separate thread that once in a while claims ownership on all objects in a DB it does not own yet. Possible, but not a very clean solution IMO...

Answer (score 0):

To follow the DAC concept, you own the object created then you can customise grants to it, so no way to prevent dropping it unless a higher role in same RBAC hierarchy claims ownership, and grant back some or ALL privileges of the object to that role.

So, for your requirement here another separate process/user need use PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE to claim objects ownership and grant back ALL PRIVILEGES on that object to role PROD_EL_ROLE

```
USE ROLE PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE;
grant ownership on ALL TABLES in SCHEMA TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA
    TO ROLE PROD_SYSADMIN_ROLE;
grant ALL PRIVILEGES on ALL TABLES in SCHEMA TESTDB.TESTSCHEMA
    TO ROLE PROD_EL_ROLE;
```

Now the role PROD_EL_ROLE can do all DML operations but no DDL operations on it again (dropping/modifying the definition of the object).